# Best way to test if a Type is a collection

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a method that accepts a parameter **obj** of type System.Object

Now I want to check if the actual type of obj is:

- A collection type (IEnumerable).
- Anything else.

The first way I thought of is:

```
if (obj is IEnumerable) 
   // obj is a collection
```

But System.String implements IEnumerable, and **I don't want to treat string as a collection**.

The second way I thought is testing for ICollection instead of IEnumerable, since IEnumerable is more of a potential collection than an actual one. This would leave out string, but also ICollection-Of-T because it does not inherit ICollection (IEnumerable-Of-T is the only generic collection abstraction that's backwards compatible - it inherits IEnumerable).

So I guess the best way is:

```
if (obj is string) 
  // not a collection
else if (obj is IEnumerable) 
  // collection
else
  // not a collection
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I view enumerables as SEQUENCES, not as COLLECTIONS. There is possibly a subtle difference in meaning there; since I don't know your application, I don't know whether that is relavent. We faced this problem when designing collection initializers. There are lots of "collections" which do not implement ICollection, and there are lots of objects which implement Add which are not collections. (Math objects, typically.) We decided to use a heuristic. If a type both implements IEnumerable and has a public Add method, it's probably a collection. This is a bit goofy, but in practice it works.

Comment: This is a good related resource about collection abstractions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're over complicating this a bit.  If you really want to use IEnumerable but exclude System.String, why not just do that directly in code?

```
public static bool IsCollection(object obj) {
  return obj is IEnumerable && !(obj is String);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it. I think when the BCL guys designed the String type they didn't realized how important IEnumerable would become as the only way to refer to any collection.

Answer (score 5):

If you really only want to test:

```
bool isCollection = obj.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Any(iface => iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
```

But frankly, if you really only want to special-case `string` (why, by the way?), then just do so. If you test for `ICollection<>`, you will treat the result of a LINQ query as "non-collection", for example, for no good reason.

Comment: Or `obj.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.IEnumerable") != null`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do a check and get true for tpyes (includes nullables) any list/collection/IEnumerable, but get false for type of string, then

```
   private static bool IsIEnumerable(Type requestType)
   {
      var isIEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(requestType);
      var notString = !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(requestType);
      return isIEnumerable && notString;
   }
```